# How to implement Windows 10 Start Menu hash mark jump list feature on Windows 10 Enterprise edition

Tags: windows-10

On my home PCs running Windows 10 there is a nice feature in the Start Programs interface. It is an entry at the top of the list of applications that is just a hash mark, but when it is selected it opens a grid of letters from A to Z that allow the user to click on any letter and jump down to the point in the list of applications whose names start with the selected letter.

My company PC at my work is also running Windows 10 but it doesn't have this handy hash mark jump list feature. It is running Windows 10 Enterprise edition version 1903, build 18362.1082.

Is the hash mark jump list feature available in this release of Windows 10? If so, how can it be turned on?

Comment: Your company PC has a version of Windows more than a year old. I am pretty sure the feature you see at home and that I have here was available on that version.  (a) Update the computer.  (b) Ask Company IT Support - they may have a policy to limit this.

Answer (score 0):

The hash mark appears to show that there are shortcuts starting with a number. Choose the first letter in the list. Home editions have a shortcut called `3D Viewer`. So home will have a hash mark for that shortcut.

Comment: Truly you have a dizzying intellect.